# How do I select one row but no more from foreign key ? ---- Group BY ---

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have this statement that works fine without the below statement.

I think I may be using the incorrect statement. What I'm trying to do is only select the first **productsapplied.applicationid**. If another row has the same **productsapplied.applicationid** as one already selected it won't select it. There can be more than one of the same application id but I need it to only add 1.

> DISTINCT('productsapplied'.applicationid)

```
'SELECT `productsApplied`.id, DISTINCT(`productsApplied`.applicationid) 
 FROM  `productsapplied` 
 INNER JOIN `products` 
 ON `productsApplied`.productid = `products`.id 
 INNER JOIN `applications` 
 ON  `productsApplied`.applicationid = `applications`.id  
 WHERE `applications`.clubid = ? AND `applications`.area = ? AND  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `applications`.date) = ? AND `products`.producttype = ?
```

If anyone has any ideas, would appreciate it! 
If not I was thinking of just doing a `COUNT DISTINCT`

Lets say that here are the products applied

id: 3 clubid:6 applicationid: 5 ...

id: 4 clubid:6 applicationid: 5 ...

id: 5 clubid:6 applicationid: 5 ...

id: 4 clubid:6 applicationid: 6 ...

Presuming the rest of the statement holds e.g. year = ? etc..

Then the number of rows returned would be 2. AS there are 3 rows with the same application id. No matter how many rows there are with the same application id, one should be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is applied is to whole row not to a single column for your concern there will be different `productsApplied.id`s per `applicationid` so you can grab all by using `group_concat`

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(pa.id),
    `pa`.applicationid 
FROM
  `productsapplied` pa
  INNER JOIN `products` p
    ON `pa`.productid = `p`.id 
  INNER JOIN `applications`  a
    ON `pa`.applicationid = `a`.id 
WHERE `a`.clubid = ? 
  AND `a`.area = ? 
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `a`.date) = ? 
  AND `p`.producttype = ?
GROUP BY `pa`.applicationid
```

If you are not concerned with `productsApplied.id`s  then you can simple use the group by part but note group by without aggregate function will result in indeterminate order

**Edit**

This will give you one max id per applicationid

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pa.id ORDER BY pa.id DESC), 1),
    `pa`.applicationid 
FROM
  `productsapplied` pa
  INNER JOIN `products` p
    ON `pa`.productid = `p`.id 
  INNER JOIN `applications`  a
    ON `pa`.applicationid = `a`.id 
WHERE `a`.clubid = ? 
  AND `a`.area = ? 
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `a`.date) = ? 
  AND `p`.producttype = ?
GROUP BY `pa`.applicationid
```

or

```
SELECT 
  MAX(pa.id),
    `pa`.applicationid 
FROM
  `productsapplied` pa
  INNER JOIN `products` p
    ON `pa`.productid = `p`.id 
  INNER JOIN `applications`  a
    ON `pa`.applicationid = `a`.id 
WHERE `a`.clubid = ? 
  AND `a`.area = ? 
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `a`.date) = ? 
  AND `p`.producttype = ?
GROUP BY `pa`.applicationid
```

Comment: hi, what I was trying to do is to get it to return only 1 from a group. So say i use group concat on pa.applicationid, I only need 1 result to be returned from the group rather than all of them grouped? I'm confused on how this works.

Comment: @vinnie667 is there any criteria to pick 1 id from a group or any id from a group

Comment: I'll create an example

Comment: @vinnie667 see my updated answer this will give you one id per applicationid

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent my whole evening on this

Answer (score 0):

```
Select min(pa.id), pa.applicationid
From productsapplied pa
Join ...
...
Group by pa.applicationid
```